# Pygame go to x location then y and back to x location for n times

Tags: python, pygame

I´m trying to move my player to my spaceship location first then return for the unitsleft and go to spaceship again for n times according to units left, here is my code.
I think the idea of movement is not bad but the code maybe wrong I think.
Thanks to everyone:
Here is my code:

I´m using as an example unitsize = 2, but it can be up to 4

```
 if self.hasunit == False and self.isreturning == False:
        # If player collides with unit
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, unit_group, False):
            # OBTENER COORDENADAS DE X Y Y DE LA UNIDAD
            unitx = self.rect.x
            unity = self.rect.y
            # IF UNIT IS ONE
            if unitsize == 1:
                self.carrryingunit += unitsize
                self.hasunit = True
                self.isreturning = False
            # IF UNIT IS BIGGER THAN ONE
            elif unitsize > 1:
                self.unitsleft = unitsize
                self.hasunit = True
                self.isreturning = True
```

And as the above code is in case of hasunit = True and isreturning = True it will mean he has to go to spaceship x and spaceship y, once it gets there retrun to the unitx and unity for the left pieces and go back to spaceship coordinates, and so on, for the times, here's my other code for that part

```
#UNIT IS BIGGER THAN ONE SO IT HAS UNIT AND ITS GOING TO RETURN
    elif self.hasunit == True and self.isreturning == True:
        #EXAMPLE 2 UNITSLEFT WOULD HAVE TO GO FIRST TO SPACESHIP, ONCE COLLIDED WITH SPACESHIP, GO TO UNITX AND UNITY AND THEN TO SPACESHIP AGAIN
        while self.unitsleft < 0:
            if (self.rect.x > spaceship_x):
                dx -= 1
            else:
                dx += 1
            if (self.rect.y < spaceship_y):
                dy += 1
            else:
                dy -= 1
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, spaceship_group, False):
                if (self.rect.x > unitx):
                    dx -= 1
                else:
                    dx += 1
                if (self.rect.y < unity):
                    dy += 1
                else:
                    dy -= 1
                if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, unit_group, False):
                    if (self.rect.x > spaceship_x):
                        dx -= 1
                    else:
                        dx += 1
                    if (self.rect.y < spaceship_y):
                        dy += 1
                    else:
                        dy -= 1
                self.unitsleft -= 1
            self.hasunit = False
            self.isreturning = False
```

Also another thing I would like to implement is to destroy that object (unit) on the last collision, hope I was clear with my explanation, and thanks to all of you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described what happens if you run the code and what's not working, so I am finding it difficult to tell what exactly doesn't work. On the other hand, I think there is a simpler way to approach this problem than doing collision detections and having so many if statements and that is what my answer is about.

When there is something that alternates, I always like to consider using the sin or the cosine function. My solution uses the cosine function. The reason is because these functions always return a value between -1 and 1 depending on what value you pass in as argument. Cosine maps your input parameter values in the following way ( you can see that it alternates).

```
[0, pi] -> [1, -1] and [pi, pi * 2] -> [-1, 1] and so on...
```

In your case, we can create a direction vector from player to the spaceship that is influenced by this cosine value so that it switches between going towards the ship and back to it's original position.

Here is an example. I have tried to comment it but feel free to ask any question.

```
import pygame
import sys
import math

startPos = [50, 50]

#set player pos to start pos. Notice it is
#copied by value because we will need startPos
#later
playerPos = startPos[:]
playerLastFrame = startPos[:]

#targerPos is where your spaceship is
targetPos = [400, 500]

#calculate the direction and distance once
direction = (targetPos[0] - playerPos[0], targetPos[1] - playerPos[1])
totalDistance = math.hypot(*direction)

#create a unit direction vector 
unitDir = (direction[0] / totalDistance, direction[1] / totalDistance)

speed = 0.001

#as you can see from the cosine mapping above,
#cos(math.pi) is 0, which is at the starting pos.
#1 is the destination. You can start at the destination
#by setting angle to 0.
angle = math.pi

#the number of rounds you want to travel
nRounds = 2

#total distance travelled. This will be used to
#determine whether or not to stop
totalDistanceTravelled = 0

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()

    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    #alpha is simply what ever the cos function returns
    #mapped between 0 and 1 since its easier to work with.
    alpha = (math.cos(angle) + 1) * 0.5

    #only want to keep travelling if the total distance is
    #less than what how much we want to travel i.e travel nRounds
    #times
    if totalDistanceTravelled  <  totalDistance * nRounds:
        #the rate at which the angle is incremented
        #can be used to simulate speed because the
        #faster we increment it the faster alpha will change.
        angle += speed

    #current distance is some fraction of totalDistance.
    #Since we have mapped alpha from 0 to 1, currentDistance
    #will go from 0 to totalDistance.

    #   alpha    currentDistance
    #  [0, 1] -> [0, totalDistance]
    currentDistance = alpha * totalDistance
    playerLastFrame = playerPos[:]

    # set the players position 
    playerPos[0] = (unitDir[0] * currentDistance) + startPos[0]
    playerPos[1] = (unitDir[1] * currentDistance) + startPos[1]

    
    totalDistanceTravelled += math.hypot(abs(playerLastFrame[0] - playerPos[0]), abs(playerLastFrame[1] - playerPos[1]))

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (0, 255, 0), startPos, 5)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 0, 0), targetPos, 5)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (0, 0, 0), (playerPos[0], playerPos[1]), 6)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: It was not the thing I was searching for, but you gave me an idea, thank you